# How to diff a selected part of two files?

Tags: vimdiff, selection

I have two files with some similar program functions in. But these functions are not ordered

```
File 1:       | File 2:
function a    | function c
              |
function b    | function e
              |
function c    | function a
```

Now I want compare "function a" from file 1 with this from file 2, and so with "function c".

The only thing I can think of is to put the parts to diff in own files. But I don't like this idea (as you can think of).

So how can I select a part of a file on my left pane and one on my right pane and start a diff?

It would be great, if this works for the same file either, to comepare e.g. "function a" and "function b" in file 1.

Comment: you can use the [linediff.vim plugin](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/linediff.vim) or my [NrrwRgn plugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn/) for such

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt - Looks fine to use for comparing parts of one file with another in itself. :) Is there a posibility for two files too? (Something sounds that I should use Emacs for such things...)

Comment: With linediff plugin, you select 2 areas in visual mode (regardless of the files/buffers) they are from, and run `:LineDiff`, which sounds like what you would need.

Answer (score 2):

I have a same problem so I developed and posted [spotdiff.vim](https://github.com/rickhowe/spotdiff.vim), which provides commands and custom operators to select a range of lines and text area to compare partially in everywhere within windows. Please try to use and enjoy it.