# How can I diff two files from different start positions?

Tags: vimdiff

In an editing session I have 2 buffers in 2 windows.

I would like to compare a part of file 1 with a part of file 2.

The normal way is to use

```
:diffthis
```

in the two buffers. But the comparison begins at the beginning of the files and the cursor positions are lost.

I know that two plugins to vim exist for such tasks:

linediff.vim

and

spotdiff.vim

as discribed in

https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/33313/how-to-diff-a-selected-part-of-two-files

Formerly I had used the plugin LineDiff with great success.

My question aims to cases when plugins are not available and cannot be installed for some reasons.

Is there a way to view the diff as wanted with vimdiff?

Comment: All LineDiff is doing is taking the two blocks and putting them in two temp files and then doing normal `:diffthis` between them. Should be easy to implement. You should try to do it yourself and ask for help with specific hurdles.

Comment: What is preventing you to install the linediff plugin on Knoppix?

Comment: What is preventing you to install the linediff plugin on Knoppix? – 
Christian Brabandt

Comment: regarding: What is preventing you to install the linediff plugin on Knoppix? 
Christian Brabandt
 my answer: because aptitude and apt-get had removed very many essential packages (as reported in another post) I am on the way to re-install them and to compare state after re-install with original state, in this situation I dare not apply package menagment tools.

Comment: regarding: What is preventing you to install the linediff plugin on Knoppix?  
Christian Brabandt
 my anwer: because aptitude and apt-get had deleted very many essential packages  (as reported in anither post), I am on the way to re-install them. In this state I dare not apply package managment tools for installation.

Comment: regarding spotdiff.vim: there is an answer/comment about the plugin spitdiff.vim.. This is new for me. Very, very many thanks.

Comment: typo: spotdiff.vim,

Comment: edited on 13.10.2022 in order to point to differences to an existing similar answer.  -- Anton Wessel

Comment: edited 13.10.2022 in order to point to differences to an existing similar answer - Anton Wessel

Comment: @AntonWessel you do not need any package management tools. Just `git clone https://github.com/AndrewRadev/linediff.vim ~/.vim/pack/dist/start/linediff`

Comment: comment to @Christian Brabandt, Oct 13 2022: Your hint to use "git clone" is the essential key hint. By this installing a plugin runs without any problems, without touching apt history etc. I hope, most plugins could be installed by this way.

Comment: comment to @Christian Brabandt, Oct 13 2022: Your hint to use "git clone" is the essential key hint. By this installing a plugin runs without any problems, without touching apt history etc. I hope, most plugins could be installed by this way. Remark 1: Now I remembert that "git clone" I used some years ago. Remark 2: Nevertheless the such installed "LineDiff" I still was not able to mk usable, there is some work after needed, I also have forgotten. Remark 3: I was not able to write this comment, my thanks, earlier since I lost 130 filles due to Android, recover ishard, timestamps not preserved

Comment: to @Christian Brabandt, Oct 13 2022: Your hint to use "git clone" is the essential key hint. By this installing a plugin runs without any problems, wo touching apt history etc. I hope, most plugins could be installed by this way. Remark 1: Now I rem  "git clone" I used some years ago. Remark 2: Nevertheless the such installed "LineDiff" I still was not able to mk usable, there is some work after needed, I also have forgotten. Remark 3: I was not able to write this comment, my thanks, earlier since I lost 130 filles due to Android, recover ishard, timestamps not preserved – 
Anton Wessel